# How to check if regex is infinite

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

example:

```
try{
    var user_regex = "/\\b(.*)\\b/gi"; //user typing own regex

    //... throw if regex is infinite

    var regex = new RegExp(user_regex);
catch(e){
    console.error(e);
}
```

How to prevent this situation?

Thank you, for help.

Comment: what do you mean by `infinite` related to a regular expression?

Comment: Regex in example is executing infinite. See: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=114934

Comment: It is because the pattern can match an empty string.

Comment: User can typing pattern. How to prevent it?

Comment: test it over an empty string. if the match is valid refuse the regexp

Comment: [Doesn't happen on another tester though](https://regex101.com/r/zpFtAC/2)

Comment: Ohh, I see. I'll try to do it.

Comment: the regex can return an empty string but the empty string doesn't match because of word boundary. `var user_regex=/\b(.*)\b/g; [ user_regex.exec('abc def'), user_regex.exec('abc def'), user_regex.exec('abc def') ];` and will never return null